# React-Redux Form not returning values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have setup React-Redux form, but upon submit I am getting an empty object in the `console.log()`

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {stockSave} from '../actions/actions';

class Stock extends React.Component {
    customHandler(values){
        console.log(values);
        //this.props.stockSave(values);
    }
    render() {
        const {fields: {id}, handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.customHandler)}>
                <input type="text" {...id} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
};
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm',
    fields: ['id']
}, null, {stockSave})(Stock);
```

After submitting the form, I get empty object in the console. Here is the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/lzNoKPwsLU

Any help regarding this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor in your class and bind your customHandler function.

```
class Stock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.customHandler = this.customHandler.bind(this);
    }
    customHandler(values){
        console.log(values);
        //this.props.stockSave(values);
    }
    render() {
        const {fields: {id}, handleSubmit} = this.props;
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.customHandler)}>
                <input type="text" {...id} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
};
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myForm',
    fields: ['id']
}, null, {stockSave})(Stock);
```

And why are calling handleSubmit from pros and passing your customHandle as parameter?

I think that you want to call your handleSubmit this would be better:

```
customHandler(values){
     this.props.handleSubmit();
     console.log(values);
     //this.props.stockSave(values);
}
```

Comment: What are theses values that you are passing? I think that there is the problem

Comment: Passing just an int value like 123

Comment: That is the problem, from where are you passing this int? Try this: <form onSubmit={() => { this.customHandler(5); }}>

Comment: But why its not picking up the value from formfield

Comment: I did not work with redux form, but I think this example is great: http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/simple/ did you try use it?